# pointwise convergence but not L1 convergence

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f_{n}$ be a family of nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions on [0,1] with the property that $\sup\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}\ln(2+f_{n})\leq M$ for some constant M. Suppose $f_{n}$ converges pointwise a.e. to a measurable function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbf{R}$. Prove or disprove the claim that $||f_{n}-f||_{1}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

I can prove that the integrals of $f_{n}$ are bounded by 2M and $f$ is integrable. I have tried some easy functions like characteristic functions and the claim seems to be true. I don't know whether there is a counterexample.

Comment: There is no counter-example. Do you know the concept of uniform integrability? (Using it we can show that $\|f_n-f\|_1 \to 0$).

Comment: I don't know how to prove $f_{n}$ are uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln (2+N)\int_{\{f_n >N\}} f_n \leq \int_{\{f_n >N\}} f_n \ln (2+f_n)\leq M$ so $\int_{\{f_n >N\}} f_n <\epsilon$ for all $n$ whenver $\frac M {\ln (2+N)} <\epsilon$. This proves that $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable. (according the the definition in K L Chung's book, for example). Since $f_n \to f$ a.e. it follows that $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$.

Edit: To use your definition of uniform integrabilty do the following:
Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $\delta=\frac {\epsilon} N$. If $m(A) <\delta$ then $\int_A f_n = \int_{A \cap (f_n >M)} f_n+\int _{A \cap (f_n \leq N)} f_n \leq \int_{(f_n >M)}f_n+Nm(A) <2\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. There is a typo, the leftmost side is ln(2+N).

Comment: @Acorn Right. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Acorn I am using the definition of uniform integrability that is commonly uses in Probability Theory, e.g. K L Chung's book . [A family of measurable functions $(X_i)$ on probabiltiy space is uniformly integrable  if $\sup_n\int_{|X_i|>N} |X_i| \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$] .Rudin uses a different definition.  I don't what book you are using.

Comment: I thought it worked but I'm confused now.  This is not the uniform integrability that I know. Given $\epsilon>0$, uniform integrability requires a $\delta$ depending only on $\epsilon$ s.t. whenever $m(A)<\delta$, we have $\int_{A}|f_{n}|<\epsilon$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Acorn That is called uniform absolute continuity. That condition  plus the condition that $\int |f_n|$ is bounded is equiavalent to the condition I have stated.

Comment: I'm using Royden's and Rudin's books.

Comment: I have edited the answer. It now uses your own definition of uniform intergbability. BTW this argument is very useful. You should remember this definition of uniform intergbability. @Acorn

Comment: It's clear now to me. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, if $\mu$ is a finite measure, a bounded set $\mathcal F\subset L^1(\mu)$ is uniformly integrable if and only if there exists a function $\Phi\colon [0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ with superlinear growth at $\infty$ (i.e. $\Phi(\lambda)/\lambda\to \infty$ as $\lambda\to\infty$) such that $\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}\int \Phi(|f|)\,d\mu<\infty$. This is called de La Vallée Poussin's criterion and the proof is essentially the same as the argument from this answer. For the example at hand, you can apply it to $\Phi(\lambda)=\lambda\log(2+\lambda)$.